# Could these unicorns be used to herald a new era of Captchas?

Tags: discussion, captcha, unicorns

Everyone's unique - only humans can tell a unicorn apart from a hostile takover of their account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea isn't totally new, see http://mattt.github.com/Chroma-Hash/

Comment: @balpha: You created this? I think, it's fantastic. I'll vote you up, nice unicorn you created indeed :-)

Comment: @balpha: I don't even know why I'm mentioning this, but there's a typo in your profile description...

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Took me a while to find it :) Fixed, thanks!